# Booting time dongle auto-detection not happening - usb modeswitch

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, usb-modem, usb-modeswitch

I have an issue with USB dongle detection. It works as expected if we plug in the dongle after boot. But it  fails, if I reboot with the dongle connected. I verified the USB_ModeSwitch log(added below). It seems the USB_ModeSwitch reads the dongle path wrongly. Please help me in resolving this problem.

1. OS Version : **Ubuntu 18.04.4 Server LTS (GNU/Linux 4.19.126.mptcp x86_64)**
2. USB_ModeSwitch version : **usb-modeswitch 2.5.2+repack0-2ubuntu1**
3. Also see the USB_ModeSwitch log (`/var/log/usb_modeswitch.log`) below :

   ```
   USB_ModeSwitch log from Mon Sep 21 11:50:44 2020
   Use global config file: /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf
   Raw args from udev: 1-4.2.2-1-4.2.2:1.0:1.0
   Bus ID for device not given by udev.
   Trying to determine it from kernel name (1-4.2.2-1-4.2.2:1.0:1.0) ...
   Top device directory not found (/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4.2.2-1-4.2.2)! Exit.
   ```